# redirection and pipeline

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

I was wondering about differences and relation between redirection and pipeline.

1. Is pipeline only used to connect
   stdout output of a command to stdin
   input of another command?
2. Is redirection only used to connect
   a stdout output of a command to a
   file, and to connect a file to a
   stdin input of a command? But there
   seems to be `command >& 2`.
3. A pipeline `com1 | com2` can be
   replaced by redirection as `com1 >
   tempfile; com2 < tempfile`. Can the
   replacement be modified to be
   without using a file?
4. Can a redirection be replaced by a
   pipeline?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to post many questions in one. Here, the questions are strongly related, so it works, but usually it's better to post them separately, with a bit more context to it (e.g. “I ran this command line and that command line and I don't understand why they have different results”). Given your focus on learning, I suggest a book and experimentation (ask here when you don't understand something in the book or the result of your experiment, or want to know more). By the way, please don't use “tag lines” like “Thanks and regards”, they're implied (thank by voting/accepting).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes. More precisely, in the shell, a pipe connects the standard output of the command on the left to the standard input of the command on the right. Even more precisely, what `foo | bar` means to the shell is:

   1. Create a [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_%28Unix%29).
   2. Fork a child process, and connect the write end of the pipe to its standard output. Then execute `foo` in this child process.
   3. Fork a child process, and connect the read end of the pipe to its standard input. Then execute `bar` in this child process.
   4. Wait for both child processes to exit.
2. Yes. Ordinary redirections indicate a file by name: `>foo`. Another form of redirection indicates a file by [descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor). For example, `>&2` means “redirect standard output to whatever file descriptor 2 is currently connected to”.

   On that topic, note that redirections are processed from left to right. For example, to redirect both standard output and standard error to the same file, use `foo >filename 2>&1`. The command `foo 2>&1 >filename` typed in a terminal would first connect standard error to the terminal (which both standard output and standard error are still connected to at that point, so it wouldn't make any difference), then connect standard output to the file.
3. Yes, but. The pipe construct in the shell creates an anonymous pipe; there are also [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

   ```
   mkfifo f
   cat f
   # (in another terminal)
   echo hello >f
   ```

   Named pipes are a lot rarer than pipelines. They're used when it's necessary to connect two processes that are started independently; this doesn't happen very often, but it's nice to have it when necessary.

   Note that the replacement you gave: `foo >tempfile; bar <tempfile` is different: first `foo` writes all of its output to the temporary file, then `bar` starts running. With a pipeline, the commands run in parallel.
4. Yes, but it's not very useful.

   ```
   cat input_file | some_command   # a uselessly complicated way of writing some_command <input_file
   echo hello | tee output_file    # a uselessly complicated way of writing echo hello >output_file
   ```

Comment: I am a little confused with the paragraph which starts with 'On that topic, note that redirections are processed from left to right......' on the **2.** section. I found this statement conflicts with your later explanation. To apply this principle to the `foo >filename 2>&1`, does it mean, it first redirect the stdout to `filename` and then redirect stderr to whatever file descriptr stdout is connectted to?

Comment: @yangchenyun `foo >filename 2>&1` means first redirect stdout to `filename`, then redirect stderr (= file descriptor 2) to the file that stdout (= file descriptor 1) is connected to.

Comment: I see, it is different from `foo 2>&1 >filename`.

Answer (score 4):

1) Yes (beside stderr)

```
prg 2>&1 | workwithboth
```

2) Yes (beside stderr).

3) No. Not exactly.

```
com1 > tempfile; com2 < tempfile.
```

will start com2 after finishing com1, while

```
com1 | com2
```

might process the beginning of the output of com1 with com2 immediately. And yes - without a file: Use a pipeline.

4) You can use a window as a door, and a door as a window, but why should you? There were reasons to build doors and windows - they didn't fall from the sky.

Comment: Thanks! 1) what do you mean by the example? I was talking about pipeline only. 2) what do you mean by "besides stderr"? 3) Do you mean without using a file, pipeline can be replaced by redirection? 4) My question is for me to understand pipeline and redirection, not for real applications.

Comment: 1) You can pipeline the errorstream too. 2) redirection works for the errorstream too (&2) 3) No, I said the difference is, that the first cmd1 isn't finished, when cmd2 is started, opposed to using a file. 4) The example is to understand that doors and windows have different strengths, but if you insist, you can use them differently.